# Generar e Insertar en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

Tengo la siguiente función que genera un pin aleatorio cada que se ejecuta y me gustaría saber que al mismo tiempo se ingrese en una tabla a una base de datos de MySQL cada que se ejecute y si puedo traer la conexión con la herencia cómo 'require 'funcs/conexion.php''?

```
<?php
require 'funcs/conexion.php';
function pass($length)
{
$charset    =   "ABC0123456789";
$pwn    =   "";
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
{
    $ran = rand(0,(strlen($charset)));
    $pwn .= substr($charset,$ran,1);
} return $pwn;
}
echo "Su PIN de Acceso a cuestionarios es: ";
echo pass(10);
?>
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Si a todo. Podrias aclarar un poco mas cual es el problema que tenes?

Comment: Sólo me gustaría hacer que cada que genere dicho PIN lo inserte a la base de datos al mismo tiempo y así cada que se cree uno diferente. Se que debo implementar la consulta pero no se cómo hacerlo dentro de la misma función.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Aclara mas tu problema. Que es lo que no podes hacer? conectarte a la base de datos? tirar un query a la base de datos? traer resultados de la misma? que investigaste o probaste?

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado mi problema de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
try{
    $sqlconnection = new 
pdo('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8','root','');
}catch(PDOException $pe){
    echo 'Cannot connect to database';
    die;
}

$caracteres = '123ANBCF';
for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++){
$aleatoria = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres), 0, 6);
echo $aleatoria . "\n";
}

$commandtext = 'INSERT INTO pmytable (pin) VALUES (:aleatoria)';
$cmd = $sqlconnection->prepare($commandtext);
$cmd->bindParam(':aleatoria', $aleatoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cmd->execute();
?>
```